# Browsing Database error happends while the code compiles

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2017

In particularly, working with gdiplus.h, its definitions like `ULONG_PTR` and `GdiplusStartup` are shown as Browsing Database errors while the code compiles. Clear Database Errors or rescan do not help, the terms stay underlined. Does anyone know how to fix it?

> (Severity Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State Error
>   (active)  E0020   identifier "ULONG_PTR" is undefined      )

Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2017 Version 15.8.8

Answer (score 0):

I have found how to fix it. Copy the lines containing underlined characters, and paste them directly over themselves. (It means, copy, delete, paste at the same place). :)